# I'm using Rails 5, but Rails is still requiring a database.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 5 and I access my credentials by using `RAILS_ENV=production EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit`. However, when I run `rails c -e production`, it gives me this error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:185:in `database_configuration': Cannot load database configuration:
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"] (RuntimeError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:133:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:328:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
```

Why is this file being required? How do I ignore it? Just for kicks, I set up a `config/database.yml` file that looks like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 200
  port: 25060
production:
  <<: *default
  host: <%= Rails.application.credentials.production[:host] %>
  username: <%= Rails.application.credentials.production[:username] %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.credentials.production[:password] %>
  database: <%= Rails.application.credentials.production[:database] %>
development:
  <<: *default
  host: <%= Rails.application.credentials.development[:host] %>
  username: <%= Rails.application.credentials.development[:username] %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.credentials.development[:password] %>
  database: <%= Rails.application.credentials.development[:database] %>
```

However, when I run `rails c -e production`, I still get this error:

```
(erb):14:in `<main>': Cannot load database configuration:
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `result'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:172:in `database_configuration'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:133:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
```

I can access the development instance just fine, but not production. Not quite sure why this file is required if Rails 5 is supposedly moving away from it.

Comment: Rails still requires a `database.yml` in version 6.

Comment: Where did you get that recent versions of Rails are moving away from the database configuration file?

Comment: Well I thought I read awhile ago that since the credentials aren't stored there anymore then it would be irrelevant... but I guess not